# gatsby blog starter makes linked images

Tags: reactjs, markdown, gatsby

currently i'm have issue with generating html with [gatsby-transformer-remark](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-transformer-remark/). 
The problem is, converted `markdown` to `html` has images with a link, and transformed to sth like :

```html
<a class="gatsby-resp-image-link" href="/static/8058f3f26913fea3b6a89a73344fe94a/2b40c/salty_egg.jpg" style="display: block" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
    <span class="gatsby-resp-image-background-image" style="padding-bottom: 75%; position: relative; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; background-image: url(&quot;data:image/jpeg;base64,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&quot;); background-size: cover; display: block; transition: opacity 0.5s ease 0.5s; opacity: 0;"></span>
  <img class="gatsby-resp-image-image" alt="Chinese Salty Egg" title="Chinese Salty Egg" src="/static/8058f3f26913fea3b6a89a73344fe94a/c739e/salty_egg.jpg" srcset="/static/8058f3f26913fea3b6a89a73344fe94a/8ee9c/salty_egg.jpg 148w,
/static/8058f3f26913fea3b6a89a73344fe94a/ebbe7/salty_egg.jpg 295w,
/static/8058f3f26913fea3b6a89a73344fe94a/c739e/salty_egg.jpg 590w,
/static/8058f3f26913fea3b6a89a73344fe94a/5413e/salty_egg.jpg 885w,
/static/8058f3f26913fea3b6a89a73344fe94a/4efde/salty_egg.jpg 1180w,
/static/8058f3f26913fea3b6a89a73344fe94a/2b40c/salty_egg.jpg 2048w" sizes="(max-width: 590px) 100vw, 590px" loading="lazy" style="opacity: 1; transition: opacity 0.5s ease 0s; color: inherit; box-shadow: white 0px 0px 0px 400px inset;">
  </a>
```

starter blog [demo](https://gatsby-starter-blog-demo.netlify.com/hello-world/) hello-world post has this link on image.

I am looking a way to remove that link and use [medium-zoom](https://github.com/francoischalifour/medium-zoom) package instead.
thanks in advance